# Generate AAR file with all dependencies

Tags: android, facebook, google-play-services, facebook-android-sdk, aar

I am facing problems in generating AAR file with all the dependencies required. Following is the configuration for build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "3.5.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.14.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'
}
```

I am trying to add the generated AAR file using File > New Module > Import .JAR/.AAR package. But, it is unable to include all external dependencies, Facebook and Google Play Services to be specific. The error says:

```
Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@integer/google_play_services_version').
```

And, it is unable to find com.facebook.FacebookActivity in AndroidManifest.xml.

Please help me in resolving this issue.

**Update**

Tried building using pom.xml, but of no use.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.loginradius.androidsdk</groupId>
    <artifactId>loginradius-android-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.0</version>
    <packaging>aar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <!-- use UTF-8 for everything -->
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.facebook.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>facebook-android-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>4.27.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-play-services</artifactId>
            <version>r22</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.9.0-rc.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <sdk>
                        <platform>19</platform>
                    </sdk>
                    <deleteConflictingFiles>true</deleteConflictingFiles>
                    <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
                </configuration>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24325333/no-resource-found-integer-google-play-services-version-whats-this

Comment: @Lingeshwaran: I believe that might not be an appropriate solution

Comment: @HiteshPamnani May I know how you fixed the issue finally?

Answer (score 2):

If you are planning to release the lib, it will be better not to include the dependent libraries in the packaged aar and instead add the same `compile` dependencies found in lib build script inside the build script of the app as such:

`app build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    compile ':my-lib'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.14.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'
}
```

That way users of your library won't face merging conflicts when they use public libraries like your library does, gradle will automatically resolve them.

Comment: I've tried doing that. But, I am looking for a better way to include all dependencies in a single library.

Comment: I advise that you shouldn't cause then users of your lib will be facing issues as these: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38658378/2949966 https://stackoverflow.com/q/29628067/2949966 Gradle cannot resolve merging conflicts if a aar contains a certain lib packaged inside while the app as well depends on the lib and contains code calling methods from lib.

Comment: The original poster was asking "How" to accomplish this...not whether this was a good idea or not.  Just answering a post with "...you shouldn't be doing that..." isn't really an answer.  I'm here because I'm looking to do the same thing, I'm 100% aware of the problems, and I'm willing to deal with the consequences.

Comment: I have yet to see a library that requires you to list all the dependencies in your own app.

Answer (score 1):

You should generate pom file, where all dependencies will be stored.

Comment: I've tried generating pom file, but I wasn't able to build successfully. Could you please elaborate more on that?

Comment: @HiteshPamnani this pom is not from your library (because of version facebook sdk for example). Try to look how to generate it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34914603/4141049

Comment: Thanks for the help. I believe the repo should be published to maven? Or we can use it locally? In that example, the repo is being used locally. For example, maven {url "D:/full/path/to/repo"}

Comment: @shmakova It should have been a comment, not an answer. Please read FAQ

Comment: @HiteshPamnani you can publish it to local maven repository

Comment: @shmakova: But, if I've to distribute the AAR file. Then?

Comment: @HiteshPamnani if you want to distribute it, you should publish it to public repository