# Android project requesting the same import that my library has

Tags: android, aar

I Have a library that I've made, it imports the "androidx.biometric:biometric:1.0.0"
the library is a wrapper for Android biometric.
I've made an aar file and imported it to my project.

When I try to access the method in my library, it says that it can't find supertype "androidx.biometric" altough my library has it like this: 
api 'androidx.biometric:biometric:1.0.0'

If I'm adding the same dependancy in my project, it success.
(api 'androidx.biometric:biometric:1.0.0') but the whole idea is that my aar library will take care of that.

Is there any fix for this? 
am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: aar files do not include their dependencies.

Comment: Ok, so there's another way? Maybe a JAR file? If so  how can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

I can not comment on your question so I am just posting it here. Please check the link below it might answer your question: [Generate AAR file with all dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46579067/generate-aar-file-with-all-dependencies)

Comment: it's suggesting to remove dependencies from the library.. I want them inside my library. Thanks for the effort! :)